# Button that links to same product in a different category wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce, categories

I'm looking for someone who can help me out with a problem I'm running into at the moment.
I am trying to add a link onto my product page which redirects the user to the same product but under another category:

We have 2 different Bannersets for sale:

productname: Testproduct 1
productcategory: **Static** bannerset
info: A bannerset that exists of 7 sizes with a JPG extension

productname: Testproduct 1
productcategory: **Interactive** bannerset
info: A bannerset that exists of 7 formats in .jpg + HTML5 extension

now, on each individual productpage I want a link (basic html href link or button doesn't really matter) that redirects the customer to the same product but in the other category. for instance:

On the **static** bannerset product page I want a link that says:
I would like this product in the **interactive version**.
now if you click on this link, I want the customer to be redirected FROM the current url: **http://examplesite.com/shop/static-banners/testproduct-1** TO: **http://examplesite.com/shop/interactive-banners/testproduct-1**

Is there any way to do this?
I already tried fiddling around with some php codes but I only managed to get the permalink and not change the url ...

I hope my explanation was clear enough to understand.

Thanks in advance,

Joost

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/shop/interactive-banners/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
```

-add this inside the loop in your product template

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is check, under which category the product is currently display. i.e. Static bannerset or Interactive bannerset. And based on that information you can format the target link and/or the button text as well.

I assume you are okay with using the respective category slugs directly.

Following is the code for your reference.

```
//get current category object
$current_category = get_queried_object();
//get current category id and slug
$current_cat_id = $current_category->term_id;
$current_cat_slug = $current_category->slug;
//identify target category based on current category's slug.
$target_cat = ($current_cat_slug == 'static-banners') ? 'interactive-banners' : 'static-banners';
//for display text (if required)
$display_text = ($current_cat_slug == 'static-banners') ? 'I would like this product in the Interactive version.' : 'I would like this product in the Static version.'
//get target category link
$target_cat_link = get_term_link($current_category->term_id);
//display link as anchor tag
<a href="<?php echo($target_cat_link.$post->post_name); ?>"><?php echo($display_text); ?></a>
```

Hope this helps.